# How to Change Column Name In DataReader In C#?

Tags: c#, gridview, sqldatareader

I have `SqlDataReader` that gets returned from a `ExecuteDataReader` statement.

All I want is: change some column name in the data reader, just before binding to grid.

Here's the situation:

1. First I build the structure Of grid (structure is in the table in database that was filled based on the output of a stored procedure in the system in the past)
2. I execute data reader to execute stored procedure
3. Binding the data reader to the grid

Here is the problem: if one column in the stored procedure is in upper case and related column in the grid is in lower case, the grid does not fill.

And I have a lot of stored procedures based on this architecture. Some of them have many rows to display. And because of that I use data reader for performance.

1. I don't want to change the column name in the stored procedure (too much work)
2. I don't want to copy the result of data reader to another data holder (because of overhead, and low performance)
3. I just one way to change the column name of the data reader

   sqlDataReader reader;
   reader.executedatareadet();

For example after data reader is returned I have two columns (`A,B`).

I want to change column `'A'` to `'a'` (convert to lower case) before binding it to the grid like `reader.GetName(i)`

I want to be able to do something like

```
reader.SetName(i)
```

but it seams that we cant change the data reader column name

Comment: Instead of Column name try using index properties of coloumn..if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try loading the DbDataReader in a DataTable with a predefined column names and later use the table as a data source in tout application.

Comment: hi damyan Bogoev Thanks..But result Of Stored Procedure is too Much and I don't Watn to Copy to another dataholder like datatabele.

Comment: Than you zcould use a stored procedure with an ORM. Map it to a method that materializes it to a given type and you will get the data in the needed format.

Comment: Here is shown how to do that with OpenAccess ORM using low level ADO API http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/openaccess-tasks-adonet-stored-procedures-materialize-result-set.html

Answer (score 1):

1. You can change the column names in GridView
2. If possible alter the Stored Procedure with new column names

Comment: thanks Anand but in the question i mention that i don't want to do either of solution you sugest..

Comment: The DataReader is only for reading the returned data. You read the values and you put them in your own data structures or variables.

The only way to change the structure of the data reader is on the data origin in your case Stored Procedure or Data binding cotrol in your case GridView.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation here would be: separate the UI and database code. If your UI is affected by a data-reader, then that simply makes me ask: "why is the UI talking to a data-reader?". Those two things are at total opposite ends of the stack. I would abstract that by having your DAL return a concrete list of populated POCO/DTO types (or possibly view-model types), i.e.

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomers({some filter etc}) {...}
```

then bind to *that*, i.e.

```
var customers = dal.GetCustomers(...);
...
someUI.DataSource = customers;
```

The `Customer` type is then well defined with properties such as:

```
public class Customer {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Any implementation changes at the DAL are now completely separated from the UI.

Comment: Hi Marcel Thanks, you Are absolutely  right. but,in this situation for me the performance is critical.you copy data data to another dataholder.i think the only option for me is to change the Stored Procedure beacause it seem there is no way to change column name of data reader

Comment: @abianari in any scenario where there is a *sane* amount of data being bound, that will make **exactly zero** difference to performance (assuming your reader-to-POCO layer is fast; something like "dapper" would be ideal). The only performance that is going to show there is the network latency and database query performance. And indeed, even if you're binding a large amount of data, there are non-buffered / streaming ways to do the same with `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>` (and indeed, "dapper" has that built in too). Frankly: I reject your claim. I spend a **lot** of time looking...

Comment: @abianari ... at performance-critical code, and that is simply not going to be the bottleneck.

Comment: Marc thanks alot....i must implement and check the solution and i inform later.thank you very much